# Vite.js and multiple entry points

Tags: reactjs, vite

We are using Vite.js for our React app and we need to support multiple entry points and tried to solve this with this vite.js.config:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />

import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import mkcert from "vite-plugin-mkcert";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    process.env = { ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };
    return {
        base: process.env.VITE_PUBLIC_URL,
        plugins: [react(), mkcert(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgr(), eslint()],
        build: {
            outDir: "./build",
            rollupOptions: {
                input: {
                    main: "index.html",
                    officeTaskPane: "taskpane.html",
                    officeCommands: "commands.html",
                },
            },
        },
        server: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 3000,
            open: false,
        },
    };
});
```

With this configuration the "index.html", "taskpane.html" and "commands.html" are copied over to the output directory, but the script is missing in the output.

I can reduce the sample to this and it still shows the same issue:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />

import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import mkcert from "vite-plugin-mkcert";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    process.env = { ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };
    return {
        base: process.env.VITE_PUBLIC_URL,
        plugins: [react(), mkcert(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgr(), eslint()],
        build: {
            outDir: "./build",
            rollupOptions: {
                input: {
                    main: "index.html",
                },
            },
        },
        server: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 3000,
            open: false,
        },
    };
});
```

Our "index.html" looks like this (a bit reduced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">
    <head>
           <!-- ... scripts/links - not important stuff -->
    </head>
    <body class="h-full overflow-hidden">
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root" class="h-full flex dark:bg-primarybackgrounddarkmode"></div>

        <!-- Entry point -->
        <script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `index.html` should use the `src/index.tsx` file.

In the generated "index.html" the reference to the script module is missing, the output looks just like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">
    <head>
            <!-- ... scripts/links - not important stuff and NO generated script link -->
    </head>
    <body class="h-full overflow-hidden">
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root" class="h-full flex dark:bg-primarybackgrounddarkmode"></div>

        <!-- Entry point -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Now the question: What are we doing wrong? I already asked ChatGpt, Google, GitHub CoPilot and searched through the vite.js issues, but I can't find anything that explains this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was rather stupid. The solution is to use the `resolve` method, e.g.:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />

import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import mkcert from "vite-plugin-mkcert";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";
import { resolve } from "path";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    process.env = { ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };
    return {
        base: process.env.VITE_PUBLIC_URL,
        plugins: [react(), mkcert(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgr(), eslint()],
        build: {
            outDir: "./build",
            rollupOptions: {
                input: {
                    main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
                    officeTaskPane: resolve(__dirname, "taskpane.html"),
                    officeCommands: resolve(__dirname, "commands.html"),
                },
            },
        },
        server: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 3000,
            open: false,
        },
    };
});
```

I'm not sure why, because the `index.html` files were found.
Anyway - this seems to work.